# Apache2 hide port

Tags: url, redirect, url-rewriting, apache2, hide

ciao a tutti,

I have a public IP and a home router that allows me to port forward as many ports as I need.

For testing purposes I need to reach two internal IPs using HTTPS. the first site is a netscaler gateway that uses 443, and is working fine; for various reasons, I'd rather not change it.

the second IP is an apache2 raspbian-based website and should use 444 (or any other port for that matter) and here is where problems start.

I can easily reach the site from outside if I use the https://example.com:444 format; however I would like to hide the :444 at the end of the address.

I have checked several threads in this regards and all seem to offer two choices:

proxy reverse: proxypreservehost / proxypass / proxypassreverse

rewrite: rewritecond / rewriterule

I can't paste more than 2 links but these are the standard examples I found on this site.

I succesfully restart apache2 in both cases, which in my very limited knowledge means 'things are ok' but i still get the :444 at the end of the address.

hence my questions,

is it even possible to obtain what I'd like to have?

what am I doing wrong?

your input is very appreciated.

thanks

regards

leo

Comment: for some unknown reason the 'hello all' part at the beginning does not post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have 1 external IP address, you won't be able to configure your firewall to forward port 433 to different IP addresses.

One device will have to proxy (at some layer) to the other. It seems like a straightforward task in either server.